# Secondary constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I have 2 secondary constructors for a data class.

```
data class node(var type: String):parentNode(){
    constructor(type: String, value: aNode) : this(type)
    constructor(type: String, value: bNode) : this(type)
}
```

I want to return a value from a function which is node(type:String, value:aNode).

```
fun getNode(): node{
val aNode = getAnode
val type = "Bank"
val return_val = node(type,aNode)
return (return_val)}

a = getNode()
```

Now 'a' has only the 'type' but not 'aNode'.
Any idea on what am i missing here?

Comment: In Kotlin, there's an almost-universal [convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) that class names begin with a capital letter. If they don't, your code won't fail, but it _will_ confuse most people reading it!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `value` is not a property of `node` class. It is just a constructor argument. You need to put it as a property first and then initialize it from the constructor.

```kotlin
data class node(var type: String): parentNode() {
    
    var value: parentNode? = null // Assuming aNode and bNode inherit from parentNode

    constructor(type: String, value: aNode) : this(type) {
        this.value = value
    }
    
    constructor(type: String, value: bNode) : this(type) {
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to access this value using `a.value`. If the `node` class is instantiated using the primary constructor, `a.value` will be `null`.

Also, you might want to add `private set` to this `value` property so that it cannot be modified from outside. You can do the same with the `type` property (make it a `val`). Most of the times you would want to use `val` properties in a data class instead of `var`s.

(And it is recommended to follow Kotlin's [naming conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) while creating variables, classes, functions, etc.)

**Edit:** As @gidds suggested, you can also include the `value` property in the primary constructor with a default value `null` and get rid of those secondary constructors.

```kotlin
data class node(val type: String, val value: parentNode? = null)
```

Comment: Of course, if there's no more code to go into those secondary constructors, then this could be simplified much further by adding `value` to the primary constructor, with a default value of `null` — making the whole thing a one-liner! And/or you could parameterise its type, so that it would give the appropriate subclass type..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added this to the answer. From "parameterise its type", do you suggest using generics? Something like `data class <T: ParentNode> Node(val type: String, val value: T? = null)`?